# Unable to debug issue Apache cordova project in vs 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, debugging

I have install visual studio 2017 with almost all components on my PC (windows 8.1) but when I Add new Apache Cordova project and run  it will show
"**unable to start debugging. The startup project cannot be launched. Ensure that the correct project is set as the startup project. The startup project can be changed by selecting 'Set as startup project' command from right click menu solution explorer. Additionally make sure its debug settings are correctly configured in the project properties**" [image]  Other project types are work fine. Project Properties

[image]

[image]

I have already set startup project but it is not working please help

Comment: Is adb started? can you see the device/debug on chrome using chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: Are there any other options in Start list? In my VS2017, it shows "Simulate in Browser - LG G5" in Start list and it will run the app in browser. Please repair your Visual Studio to check whether there has any installation issue. And also please check your Visual Studio version to make sure it is the latest version. The latest version of VS2017 now is 15.4.3

Comment: Actually at time of installation I installed all components  and issue started, after that I remove some components by modifying installation by referencing another VS installation(Which is working fine).I think this issue is cause because of one component

Comment: @AkshayMahure Do you remember which components do you remove? I will try install them one by one in my side to confirm which one causes this issue.

Comment: @Weiwei Cai  I have install almost all components and uninstall most of them but i think those components causes problem
1. .NET Core runtime
2 .NET Framework 3.5 development tools
3  Windows 8.1 SDK

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is struggling with the same, here's the step to fix it. Go to Visual Studio "Tools" > "Extension and Updates" > then search for "Cordova". Make sure it is turned on:

[image: In case someone is struggling with the same, here's the step to fix it. Go to Visual Studio "Tools" > "Extension and Updates" > then search for "Cordova". Make sure it is turn on.]

Answer (score 0):

I just lost a couple of hours to this error. For me, the solution was to follow the instructions available at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/general-tips?view=toolsforcordova-2017#debugging):

In case that link ever dies, here is a copy of the instructions:

If you get a message in Visual Studio that says you can't start debugging your app, try these steps. Also, try these steps if no emulators or devices are listed in the debug target dropdown list.

Close all instances of Visual Studio.

Open this folder:

C:\Users\username%appdata%\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools

Rename the CoreCon folder to any other name (CoreCon will get recreated when you rebuild).

Restart Visual Studio and try again.